# Как убрать ссылки из php виджета

Tags: php

Вот код php виджета. В виджете все добавленные картинки становятся со ссылками, подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать автоматические ссылки? Конечно не трудно самому поудалять, но напакастить методом тыка не хотелось бы, поэтому задаю вопрос здесь.
Спасибо заранее!

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$img_classes = apply_filters( 'electro_bc_should_desaturate', true ) ? 'img-responsive desaturate' : 'img-responsive'; ?>
<section class="brands-carousel">
    <h2 class="sr-only"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Brands Carousel', 'electro' ); ?></h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="owl-brands" class="owl-brands owl-carousel electro-owl-carousel owl-outer-nav" data-ride="owl-carousel" data-carousel-selector="self" data-carousel-options="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $carousel_args ) ); ?>">

            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>

            <div class="item">
                <?php if ( $brand->public ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'ec_brand_link', get_term_link( $term ), $term ) ); ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
                <figure>
                    <figcaption class="text-overlay">
                        <div class="info">
                            <h4><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></h4>
                        </div><!-- /.info -->
                    </figcaption>
                <?php 
                    $thumbnail_id     = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                    $image_attributes = '';

                    if ( $thumbnail_id ) {

                        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' );

                        if( $image_attributes ) {
                            $image_src    = $image_attributes[0];
                            $image_width  = $image_attributes[1];
                            $image_height = $image_attributes[2];
                        }
                    } 


                    if ( empty( $image_attributes ) ) {

                        $dimensions   = wc_get_image_size( 'shop_thumbnail' );
                        $image_src    = wc_placeholder_img_src();
                        $image_width  = $dimensions['width'];
                        $image_height = $dimensions['height'];
                    }

                    $image_src = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $image_src ); 
                ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_src ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $term->name ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( $image_width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( $image_height ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_classes ); ?>">
                </figure>
                <?php if ( $brand->public ) : ?>
                </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- /.item -->

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div><!-- /.owl-carousel -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Если, как вы говорите, *не трудно самому поудалять*, то почему бы самому и не попробовать. Может попробовав Вы бы определили, что тот кусок кода, который Вы выставили, не имеет ничего общего с *картинками и ссылками*.

Comment: да, поменял пхп кусок, извиняюсь

Comment: вот, теперь другое дело. Нужно убрать **3 строчки** кода начиная с `<?php if ( $brand->public ) ... и по <?php endif; ?>`, а так же убрать ` </a>`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло!

Comment: отметить решением чет не пойму как..

Comment: да, это просто комментарий, Вы его уже отметили )